# 5 urns, with cards labeled 1 to 10

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm having trouble with a question, and I wanted to check my answer here. Say that we have 5 urns, with 10 balls labelled 1 to 10. We extract one ball from each urn. What is the probability that the biggest number extracted is less or equal to 7?

So, given that each extration is independent from the rest, the probability that the biggest number extracted is less or equal to 7 should be equal to (7/10)^5 = 0.16807.

Is that answer right? Or am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Balls or cards? Which one is it? :-)

Comment: So each of the $5$ urns has $10$ cards/balls?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.